# AWSのRHEL接続時に表示されるRed hatの登録について

Tags: aws, rhel, redhat

AWSのRed Hat Enterprise Linuxを使用しようとしています。
AWSのページでのインスタンス作成をし、ローカルからTera TermでSSH接続しています。
接続と同時に以下のような表示がでます。

```
This system is not registered to Red Hat Insights. See https://cloud.redhat.com/
To register this system, run: insights-client --register
```

RedHatのページに登録しておかないと今後操作で困るのでしょうか。
そもそも大前提として登録はしておくべきものなのでしょうか。
調べてもそのあたりに関しての情報がとれなかったので、ご教授いただけますと幸いです。

環境:
Windows10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(OSをインストールした) システムをRHNに登録しないと、`yum` コマンドでネットワークを経由したパッケージのアップデートを入手することができません。

AWS環境におけるRHELイメージには基本サブスクリプションが含まれているようなので、詳細は以下リンク先も参照してください。

https://aws.amazon.com/jp/partners/redhat/faqs/